# Python Tkinter Button/Entry Orientation

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, anchor, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to set the position of 3 entries/buttons. I know that it needs to be done with anchor and side,however I doesn't really understand how it works. I was trying to get them in one line, the first on the left the second on the center and the third one on the right. I managed to accomplish this,however they are in 3 different lines. Please,could someone explain it to me,how this works? Are the side and anchor values related to the previous ones?

```
import tkinter
import random
canvas=tkinter.Canvas(width=500,height=500)
canvas.pack()

def symbol(x,y,z,color):
    name=entry1.get()        
    for i in range(1,z+1):
        canvas.create_text(x,y,text='                     '+name,angle=(360/z)*i,fill=color,font='Arial 19')

def draw(coordinates):
    x=coordinates.x
    y=coordinates.y
    z=int(entry2.get())
    color=entry3.get()
    symbol(x,y,z,color)


canvas.bind('<Button-1>',draw)

entry1=tkinter.Entry(bg='red')
entry1.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM,anchor=tkinter.W)

entry2=tkinter.Entry(bg='green')
entry2.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM,anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

entry3=tkinter.Entry(bg='blue')
entry3.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT,anchor=tkinter.S)
```

Comment: Normally, `pack()` will arrange widget either vertically or horizontally.  As `entry1` and `entry2` are using same side BOTTOM, they will be arranged vertically.  Try using `side=tkinter.LEFT` and `expand=True` for the 3 entries.  Also use `anchor=tkinter.E` for `entry3`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I didn't need to use the ,,anchor=tkinter.E'' command for the entry3, to work correctly. Thanks for the support, but could you please explain me what does expand=True mean?

Comment: Glad to know it helps.  `expand=True` will make the three entries spread across the width of the window.  If not set, the three entries will be packed together at the left side of the window.  You can see the effect by removing them.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter
import random
canvas=tkinter.Canvas(width=500,height=500)
canvas.pack()

def symbol(x,y,z,color):
    name=entry1.get()        
    for i in range(1,z+1):
        canvas.create_text(x,y,text='                     '+name,angle=(360/z)*i,fill=color,font='Arial 19')

def draw(coordinates):
    x=coordinates.x
    y=coordinates.y
    z=int(entry2.get())
    color=entry3.get()
    symbol(x,y,z,color)


canvas.bind('<Button-1>',draw)

entry1=tkinter.Entry(bg='red')
entry1.place(x=0,y=485)

entry2=tkinter.Entry(bg='green')
entry2.place(x=181,y=485)

entry3=tkinter.Entry(bg='blue')
entry3.place(x=360,y=485)
```